# All programs crashing (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, memory, gpu, gaming

[image]Ok, here is my issue: I get on my PC, and realize any game I try, will close to the desktop. Computer does not shut down or experience slowness. Some programs will give no error message and some will give a message with no substantial information. I have not overclocked anything and my motherboard BIOS is on all default settings.

What I tried: I updated my drivers (No Luck), downgraded my drivers (also no luck), updated windows, and even ran some tests. I ran a RAM test through windows memory diagnostics tool, and it found no problem. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the programs.

I tested the game rainbow six siege at medium settings (the settings I usually had the game on before the issue occurred). After about 2 or 3 games it crashes mid game to the desktop. After relaunching the game, it crashes in the loading screen before i even enter a match. Relaunch it a 3rd time, and well its good for another 2 - 3 games until the cycle repeats.

In task manager, the GPU percentage spiked to 100% before closing the game. I figured it could be due to my GPU overheating. However, using MSI afterburner, my GPU never exceeded the average temperature (60C - 85C) and it was always at 65-75 degrees Celsius when the crash occurs. Also, all other percentages in task manager seemed to be completely normal during game play and crash.

Note: I tried this test about 12 times and every single first crash of the cycle was during a pre round (if you have R6 you know what I mean) and not during actual First Person gameplay. Preround is kinda like a loading screen to get into the next round of the match.

Specs: (PC is self built, and all parts are about 1 and a half a year old. No third party coolers or water cooling)
Nvidia GTX 1660 ti 8gb
2 8gb ram sticks of DDR4
Intel core I3 8100
MSI z370 A - PRO motherboard
EVGA 500 w PSU

Crash Report from game "Squad"

Source
UE4Game

Summary
Stopped working

Date
‎4/‎11/‎2020 10:36 PM

Status
Report sent

Description
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Squad\Engine\Binaries\Win64\CrashReportClient.exe

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   CrashReportClient.exe
Application Version:    4.21.2.0
Application Timestamp:  5df85162
Fault Module Name:  ntdll.dll
Fault Module Version:   10.0.18362.719
Fault Module Timestamp: 64d10ee0
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   00000000000072a6
OS Version: 10.0.18363.2.0.0.768.101
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   3e04
Additional Information 2:   3e04d71d30868ad8b9def7ea564f621c
Additional Information 3:   e097
Additional Information 4:   e0978aa50caa54d9835e9884f74c75d2

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:  0c5a5203d08046f95268ed5c4d9bbb7f (1326571070955436927)

Comment: What have you tried to fix it? What errors are coming up? etc.

Comment: I have tried changing my paging system thing for my memory, and no error message occur when things crash

Comment: What kind of crash? Program back to desktop? blue screen of death? You need many more details.

Comment: I'll be playing a game or 3d modeling in blender and it will crash to desktop. Happens after about 3 hours of in a program

Comment: Do you have anything that runs OpenGL - Blender may, but I don't use it so not sure. OGL doesn't share memory very well, so do what you can to reduce its consumption. In Adobe products you can do this in prefs. Using dual monitors will have made this worse.

Comment: OpenGL is used in blender but not in any games.

Comment: Update BIOS and all Drivers, then do a Windows 10 Repair Install. Use the Media Creation Link, second link, download and run in place. Choose the option to Keep Everything. I always ensure a good backup first. Try this and see if it provides stability. 

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Why exactly are you configuring the size of the page file instead of allowing Windows to manage that?  Be sure you are adding the necessary information required to answer your question, as an edit to your question, instead of using a comment.

Comment: Edits made. And I did the paging file thing cuz a YouTube vid told me to

Comment: Lesson: don't do what a YouTube vid tells you. Let the OS manage your page file unless you have a very specific reason not to.

Comment: Ok changed my post to include as much info as I can

Comment: Look at your application logs and find the errors that are logged before the crash. They will tell you why your programs are crashing and what files are causing it.

Comment: Please see the image I added. It was as much info I could get on the error.

Comment: Have you run a RAM test?

Comment: I ran a RAM test through windows memory diagnostics tool, and it found no problems

Comment: See [this](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/pc-crashing-in-very-unique-cases.3538214/) same error.. fixed.  Seems unlikely.. but worth a try.

Comment: thanks, will try the solution as my pc is connected into a power strip.The guy seems to have a similair issue to mine.